# change focus after selecting an item in a jquery UI autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have two fields. An autocomplete field and a simple textbox. When user selects an item from autocomplete field I want to set focus on the next field and call a function when enter key is pressed on it. Here is the code:

```
    this.initPiecesAutocomplete = function (){
        $('#product_autocomplete_input1')
            .autocomplete('ajax_products_list.php', {
                minChars: 1,
                autoFill: true,
                max:20,
                matchContains: true,
                mustMatch:true,
                scroll:false,
                cacheLength:0,
                formatItem: function(item) {
                    return item[1]+' - '+item[0];
                }
            }).result(self.getCount);

       this.getCount = function(event, data, formatted) {
        if (data == null)
            return false;
                    $('#pieceCount').focus();
                    $('#pieceCount').on('keypress', function(e) {
                            if (e.which == 13) {
                                    self.addPiece(event, data, formatted)
                            }
                    });

            }
```

After selecting an item from the autocomplete field (by pressing the enter key), instead of setting focus on the `#pieceCount`field, `self.addPiece()` is called. What's wrong?

Comment: is `self` defined anywhere?

Comment: @bencripps: Yes. self is defined. this code is part of an object.